# Why do drivers change from different versions of Windows?

Tags: drivers

I am running into a problem with drivers on different versions of Windows. Why are newer versions not backward compatible (to a certain extent)? What changes between verions of windows in the OS that requires different drivers?

Comment: You’ll have to be more specific. What hardware and versions of Windows are you talking about? Many people have been able to use the drivers for many device over several different versions of Windows. It depends on various things. Sometimes the new drivers allow it to perform better by taking advantages of new aspects of Windows, sometimes it has to be done because the whole drive-architecture of Windows has been changed.

Comment: @Synetech I am mostly talking about Windows 8/8.1, but I was wondering what in general changed.

Comment: think of it like an electric plug with male and female connectors. if you change the shape of the slot, the same prongs won't fit. Drivers 'plug in' to the kernel in much the same way, so the driver must be written to use an interface defined by the kernel. when the kernels interface changes its 'shape', the driver must change as well. I don't win8, but I would be suprised if there were signifigant differances, and would expect most drivers that work on win8 to work on 8.1. but then again, IMO, nothing about win8 makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drivers represent the nexus between your kernel and your device. As such, the driver must be written to work with the kernel, and a new kernel requires a new driver. There is some overlap for minor revisions; for instance most win2k (NT5) drivers worked on XP (NT5.1), and most vista (NT6) drivers work on win7(NT6.1), but xp drivers DO NOT work on Vista, nor do win 9x drivers work on win2k.

one example of a breaking change in kernel design, is that in version 6+, windows started requiring that all drivers be WHQL certified and digitally signed (a good idea, since malicious drivers are useful for installing undetectable malware like rootkits), but that did require many customers to buy new peripherals for their PCs after upgrading. companies were not willing to pay all the money for WHQL testing for their older devices that aren't even on the shelf anymore.